# How to open a window on click on a drop down menu button

Tags: javascript

on the click on pdf in button in a button group

html code for dropdown button

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
 Button Primary
 <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a  onclick="open_win()">Button Secondary</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

javascript part of onclick is

```
<c:url var="pdfGenerationUrl" value="/data/acess"/>
<script>
    function open_win (){

        $('#reportIds').attr("action","${pdfGenerationUrl}");
        $('#reportIds').submit();   
    }
</script>
```

how to open a new window on click on open_win

Comment: did you tried to window.open( "${pdfGenerationUrl}" ); inside open_win() method?

Comment: That might not work @gurvinder372 if the form needs to be posted. Where is the code for the form?

Comment: So, you want to open the window and then submit the form? or vice-versa? What is the relation between the two? Sorry, I couldn't understand

Comment: You mean [window.open()](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)?